# Correct regex to remove www. & .com etc from url Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I cant seem to find a way to turn

```
var testString = "www.example.com";
```

into

```
"example"
```

I am trying to use regex for this. I can do it with `.replace` etc. but I would like to know how to use the correct regular expression.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```
testString = "www.example.com";
result=testString.match(/^www\.(.*)\.com$/)[1];
```

regex :

`^` ==> start with

`www\.` ==> litteral `www.` (dot must be escape)

`(.*)`  ==> use parenthese to capture a group, `.` match anything, `*` 0 or N times

`\.com` ==> litteral `.com` (dot must be escape)

`$` ==> finish by

Answer (score 4):

```js
function getHostName(url) {
 var match = url.match(/:\/\/(www[0-9]?\.)?(.[^/:]+)/i);
 if (match != null && match.length > 2 && typeof match[2] === 'string' && match[2].length > 0) {
  var hostname = match[2].split(".");
  return hostname[0];
 }
 else {
  return null;
 }
}
 
var url1 = "http://www.example.co.uk/foo/bar?hat=bowler&accessory=cane";
var url2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059759/";
var url3 = "http://www.example.com/?q=keyword";
console.log( getHostName(url1) );
console.log( getHostName(url2) );
console.log( getHostName(url3) );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I have legit been trying to work this out for the last 6 hours!

Answer (score 2):

You can trim `www` by regular expression (because it may be optional) and throw away last part of hostname by splitting url into pieces and joining them back:

```
var testString = 'www.example.com';
result = testString.replace(/^www\./,'').split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.');
```